# Javascript get .src from specific image onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an image swapper (click smaller image and it changes the image in a larger area of the screen). But I am getting the variable `imgSrc` as undefined. I believe this is because I am not getting the source for the specific image being clicked.

```
        var imgSrc = document.getElementsByClassName('avatar-small').src;
        console.log("img Src  = " + imgSrc);
```

**HTML**:

```
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar()" src="images/avatars/1.png">
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar()" src="images/avatars/2.png">
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar()" src="images/avatars/3.png">
```

How can I make use of something using `.this` so I am actually getting the source from the image that is clicked?

The console log outputs:

```
img Src  = undefined
```

**Solution for anyone looking for a JavaScript image swapper**

*Script:*

```
function selectAvatar(this){
    var imgSrc = element.src;
    document.getElementById("avatar-big").src = imgSrc;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<img id="avatar-big" src="images/avatars/10.png />

<img class='avatar-small' onclick='selectAvatar(this)' src='images/avatars/1.png' />
<img class='avatar-small' onclick='selectAvatar(this)' src='images/avatars/2.png' />
<img class='avatar-small' onclick='selectAvatar(this)' src='images/avatars/3.png' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function from onClick() you need to pass 'this' to the function, otherwise the function itself doesn't have 'this' defined and will default to 'this' referencing the Window object.

```
<img src="xxxx.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
```

You also don't need to search by class. If you do that you'll end up getting an array of all of the elements. Just pass 'this' to the function and simplify it this way.

```
function myFunction(element) {
  var thing = element.src;
}
```

Now you've got your src and can do with it as you please!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the simple answer :) I knew this was the issue which is why I mentioned it in the OP

Comment: That's basically the same answer Irvin posted 10min before you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22723489/218196

Comment: @Francesca same as my answer and posted 10min after, why not accept mine :-( ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you must pass a reference of the current element `this`, to your `selectAvatar` function, like:

```
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="images/avatars/1.png">
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="images/avatars/2.png">
<img class="avatar-small" onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="images/avatars/3.png">
```

JavaScript:

```
function selectAvatar(el) {
    var imgSrc = el.src;
    console.log("img Src  = " + imgSrc);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RpP7h/

Answer (score 2):

In single page many elements with same class might exist making it an array so use it like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('avatar-small')[index].src;
```

For clicking part not sure about Javascript events but JQuery would offer it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on("click", ".avatar-small", function()
    {
        console.log($(this).attr("src"));
        //for changing it
        $(this).attr("src") =  "resized_image.jpg";

    });

});
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('avatar-small').[index]` is a syntax error. And where does `index` come from?

Comment: sorry remove dot before `[index]`

Comment: @Francesca index is indication use a number instead for example you have 3 elements with this class so you can use any number between 0 and 2 inclusive

Answer (score 0):

document.get **Elements** ByClassName('avatar-small') returns an array. You have to use an index, like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('avatar-small')[0]
```

Comment: This would always get the first element with that class now, not the one that was clicked.