# How get src value when click on one of the mulitple images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 images in my web page. I want to get src value every time when I clicked on any image. I tried following code but its not working with multiple images.

```
<div class="test">
                 <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename();" > <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-1.png" alt=""> </a> </div>
                  <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename();" > <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-2.png"  alt=""> </a> </div>
                  <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename();" > <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-3.png"  alt=""> </a> </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function filename(){
     //var fullPath = document.getElementsByClassName('dImage').src;
       var fullpath = document.getElementsByClassName('dImg').src

     console.log(fullPath);
     var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
     var fileid = filename.split("\deckel.")[0];
     //window.location.href = "web-rocketcreator.html?="+fileid;
     console.log(fileid);
}

</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of relevant nodes accessible by index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript get .src from specific image onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723414/javascript-get-src-from-specific-image-onclick)

Comment: @PascalLamers No, Thanks

Comment: The selected answer in Pascal's link is the correct answer. If you want to to know something about an image that you click on, set a listener on that image and not on it's parent.

Comment: @loveCoding how does the suggestion in Pascal Lamer's link not work?

Comment: @loveCoding Can you please go ahead and mark one of the answers as correct ?

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have mentioned the specific problem area, here's an alternative solution.

Instead of attaching a click event to each image you can attach one to the container and listen for events as they bubble up the DOM (known as [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).)

```js
// Grab the container, and add an event listener to it
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.test');
imageContainer.addEventListener('click', filename, false);

function filename(event) {

  // Pick out the src attribute from target element
  // (the image that was clicked on)
  const { target: { src } } = event;

  // Use the src as the basis for the rest of
  // your calculations
  var filename = src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var fileid = filename.split("\deckel.")[0];
  console.log(`web-rocketcreator.html?=${fileid}`);
}
```

```css
.test a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#" class="part-one">
    <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-1.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="part-one">
    <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-2.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="part-one">
    <img class="dImage" src="images/deckel-3.png" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Get src value from image when clicking on it

When you call a function from onClick() you can pass 'this' to the function. This way you will directly have a reference to the clicked element inside the functon

```js
<img src="xxxx.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)" />

function myFunction(element) {
  const src = element.src;
}
```

## Get src value from image when clicking on parent container

```js
<a onclick="myFunction(this)"><img src="xxxx.jpg" /></a>

function myFunction(link) {
  const src = link.children[0].src
}
```

Comment: Just link him to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723414/javascript-get-src-from-specific-image-onclick - I assume you've gotten the answer from there anyway, as the code is identical.

Comment: For the record I showed him the link but OP stated it does not help !

Comment: So why post it is an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

To get a reference to the object which triggered the click event you need to pass the keyword **this** as a parameter.

In your case this object is the `<a>` element. To get it's nested children - the `<img>` element you need to call the **.children** method which returns an array. Since there's just the image element you can directly reference it using children[0] and ultimately add the **.src** property to retrieve the source.

```js
function filename(element){
     console.log(element.children[0].src);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
                 <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename(this);" > <img class="dImage" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/20/30" alt=""></a> 
                  <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename(this);" > <img class="dImage" src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/20/30"  alt=""></a> 
                  <a href="#" class="part-one" onclick="filename(this);" > <img class="dImage" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/20/30"  alt=""></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just link him to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723414/javascript-get-src-from-specific-image-onclick - I assume you've gotten the answer from there anyway, as the code is identical.